# Rewrite all url without page name

Tags: .htaccess

I have a website that has lots of pages, and i want to rewrite url for all the pages without page name,
for example:

http://example.com?category.php?cat_name=mobile

It should become like this.
http://example.com/mumbai/mobile
dubai will be a dynamic value which will keep changed by php.

We have another one the same like this.
http://example.com?blog.php?blog_name=restaurants
http://example.com/delhi/restaurants

I have lots of pages like these mentioned above but url should hold the value of city name and page name should not be there..  Blog page will redirect to blog page and category will redirect to category page only.

I did try like this.

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule (.*)$ category.php?cat_name=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

But it didnt work because all redirections will only hit to the first url category.php and the same page only.

Comment: Note you can't have two ? in the URL .. if you want to use another attribute then you have to use ?a=1&b=2

Comment: @alblue ok tell me how? For example if i have more than 10 pages of URL having the same number of segments and parameter without page name, then how url will consider each and every page has different redirection,